# Correct grammar? 「僕は20歳大学生。」

Tags: grammar

> 僕は20歳大学生。

I feel that 20歳 is used as an adjective here. Is there any special conjugation?

Comment: You sure it's not 「僕は20歳**の**大学生。」 or 「僕は20歳、大学生。」 or something?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but people will probably still expect something in between the 歳 and the 大 even if just a space or a comma:

http://naritamasatsugu.com/2019/01/13/map-9/

> この時僕は20歳 大学生。

https://www.hayato0606.com/business/sitadumi/

> 僕は20歳、大学生の時に起業したんですが、

https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1330006.html

> 僕は20歳大学生の男です。

.

> I feel that 20歳 is used as an adjective here.

Well, he could say he was 20 years old without the university student bit, so I'm not so sure about that.